# Raspberry PI MailCheck Error

Tags: python, email, raspberry-pi

I need some help because I can't execute my **Python** script.
Please tell me where my mistakes are. Additional information: I wrote this programme on a Raspberry Pi.

```
import imapclient
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

HOSTNAME = 'imap.gmail.com'
USERNAME = ',misterx@gmail.com'
PASSWORD = 'password'
MAILBOX = 'Inbox'    #(idea:try another Label eg Geocache)

NEWMAIL_OFFSET = 0   # unread messages
MAIL_CHECK_FREQ = 666 # check mail (s)

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GREEN_LED = 4
GPIO.setup(GREEN_LED, GPIO.OUT)

try:
while True:
    print ('Start')
    GPIO.output(GREEN_LED, True)
    mail = imapclient(HOSTNAME, use_uid=True, ssl=True)
    mail.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    GPIO.output(GREEN_LED, False)
    print('Logging in as ' + USERNAME)

    select_info = mail.select_folder(MAILBOX)
    print('%d messages in INBOX' % select_info['EXISTS'])

    folder_status = mail.folder_status(MAILBOX, 'UNSEEN')
    newmails = int(folder_status['UNSEEN'])

    print "You have", newmails, "new emails!"

    if newmails > NEWMAIL_OFFSET:
        GPIO.output(GREEN_LED, True)
    else:
        GPIO.output(GREEN_LED, False)

    server.logout()
    time.sleep(MAIL_CHECK_FREQ)
except KeyboardInterrupt:   
     GPIO.cleanup ()'
```

**The shell always shows me only this output:**
*Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/pi/Mail/InboxCheck.py", line 22, in 

    mail = imapclient(HOSTNAME, use_uid=True, ssl=True)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable*

Answer (score 0):

You are using `imapclient` wrong.

Your import statement should be

`from imapclient import IMAPClient`, and

`mail = imapclient(HOSTNAME, use_uid=True, ssl=True)`

should be changed to

`mail = IMAPClient(HOSTNAME, use_uid=True, ssl=True)`